# "How to add elements to list"

Tags: c#-2.0

I am trying to add element in a list from a different method but i am not able to do.

When I am using static keyword in list then i am able to add. I don't understand how it is working.

WITH STATIC

```
 public  class QuotesController : ApiController
    {
        static List<Quote> quotes = new List<Quote>()
        {
            new Quote(){Id=0,Author="ram",Description="hhkhkhh",Title="gjgj" },
            new Quote(){Id=1,Author="shyam",Description="ououo",Title="ouo" }
             };

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Quote> Get()
        {
            return quotes;
           }

        public void Post([FromBody]Quote quote)
        {
            quotes.Add(quote);
             }
                  }
```

I expect the item to be added in list without using static.

Comment: The important part here is that you're in a WebAPI controller, and these instances live for as long as the request is processed. In other words, your request to *post* a new item to the collection uses a different instance of your `QuotesController` than a request to *get* the items in the collection. A static list is shared between both as long as the process stays alive, but if you use an instance field to hold the collection, each request will get its own collection with the default content.

Comment: But When I am creating new list with same name  in post method and adding an entry, it is still showing output of previous list..

Comment: Local variables are not shared between requests, you need something that is shared. Static is not ideal, when the process dies, so does the list, you probably want something more like a database, but local variables and instance members will not work.